# How to modify the size of the space before a chapter title in LaTeX?

Tags: latex, bibliography

I have been working with tetex on Zenwalk and now that I compile my report with texlive, the behavior is a bit different.

I would like my bibliography to fit in one page like before and I just need to change the space before the title of the bibliographie chapter.

Do you know how I can manage that?

Thanks

Comment: We're talking about the vertical space between a previous bit of text and the top of the chapter title? Haven't found anything promising. This: http://dcwww.camd.dtu.dk/~schiotz/comp/LatexTips/LatexTips.html#bibspace has some bibliography related help but does not contain the name of the length that you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to reduce the top margin space of the reference page you can 
set a `\vspace*{}` command before your `\bibliography{}`. This will force the reference page to be adjusted.
Eg:

```
\newpage
\vspace*{-2cm}
\bibliographystyle{/..../bst-files/econometrica_v2}
\bibliography{/home/.../econometrics}
```

Answer (score 2):

**The easiest is to use the [`titlesec` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/).** It provides macros for defining the appearance of sectioning titles.

The *hacker* solution is to redefine the macro from `book.cls` to your liking. The original looks like so:

```
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
```

Just changing those vspaces of vskips might be enough for you.

Comment: If this is the easiest, I'll leave the titles alone :)